# Why can't I cast this NSArray to an NSMutableArray to sort it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I am serialising some JSON data into a dictionary. The dictionary contains a "status" object, and an array of dictionaries (one key of which is "time_dropped", by which I want to sort the array).

However, I get an exception claiming that a "mutating method [was] sent to [an] immutable object". Here's the relevant piece of code. I did declare `pins` as a `NSMutableArray`, by the way.

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&localError];
NSString *status = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
NSLog(@"status: %@", status);

if ([status isEqualToString:@"Okay"]) {
    self.pins = (NSMutableArray *) [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"pins"];

    NSSortDescriptor *timeDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                           sortDescriptorWithKey:@"time_dropped"
                                           ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                            sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title"
                                            ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSArray *descriptors = @[timeDescriptor, titleDescriptor];
    [self.pins sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: Rather than apologize for the bad formatting, please just fix it, as rmaddy has kindly done for you.

Comment: or you could use the `NSArray` method `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`.

Comment: Just because you said the `pins` reference points to an `NSMutableArray` will NOT stop you from pointing it at WHATEVER you want. I could do this... `self.pins = (id)[[UIViewController alloc] init];` and the compiler won't do anything to stop me.

Comment: Note that if you need mutable arrays/dictionaries in a JSON representation, NSJSONSerialization has an option to provide that, so you don't need to make copies.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I tried to fix it, but couldn't figure out how. Relax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just turn a non-mutable array to a mutable array by casting. You need to create a new NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Or in your case:

```
self.pins = [NSMutableArray 
                 arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"pins"]];
```